# during time loop, how to get data generated in first round and so on in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm creating a code in python that repeats 10 times, but at the end of the code I would like the data generated in it to be added to the second round for sum, in the third round to take the data generated in the two and so on....

I want the values ​​of the variable ano2 to be added.

my code is as follows:

```
time = 10
while time > 0: 
    

    pls = [10, 80, 5, 0] 
    mass = [0.1, 1, 3, 4]
    agua = 40
    
   
   
    rep = [item * 0.1 for item in pls] 

    seed = [A / B  if A > 0 else 0 for A, B in zip(rep, mass)]
    print(seed)

  
    seed_bank = [item * 0.60 for item in n_seed] 
    print(seed_bank)

    
    
    if agua in range(30,50):
        germ_seed = seed_bank
    else:
       germ_seed = (tuple (item * 0.20 for item in seed_bank))

    print(germ_seed)

    ano2 = [ A - B for A, B in zip (seed_bank, germ_seed)]
    print(ano2)





    tempo -= 1
```

I already tried to insert pls = [10, 80, 5, 0] + year2 but so far it didn't work, gives me the error NameError: name 'ano2' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Could you maintain a variable outside the loop to keep track of your sum/previous loops? This could also be a list of lists that if you swap your loop condition around can be indexed and used in later loops. Hope this helps!

```
time = 0
total = 0
l_total = []

while time < 10:
    total = total + 1
    time = time + 1

    # List of lists
    l_total.append(['I', 'Calculated', 'this!'])

    # Can reference last loops list by using the time counter
    if len(l_total) > 1:
        print(l_total[time - 1])
```